# Save checkboxes to separate table using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have spaces that hold events and items that would incur charges.

On the back-end, I want to add a space and the possible charges so I have a form with multiple select checkboxes for those charges.

I want it to write the event space ID to the facility_event_spaces_id column and write the charges to facility_event_charges_id column in my 'event_charges' table.

It's not saving anything to my table, event_charges.
I may have something incorrect in the model or controller or both. Any cakephp gurus have suggestions?

We're running cakephp 1.3. thanks!

---

```
<tr>
    <td class="add">Charges:</td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('charge', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options'=>$charges)); ?>
    </td>         
    </tr>
```

[image]

---

source view of add form

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[FacilityEventSpace][charge][]" value="1" id="FacilityEventSpaceCharge1" /><label for="FacilityEventSpaceCharge1">Officials</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[FacilityEventSpace][charge][]" value="2" id="FacilityEventSpaceCharge2" /><label for="FacilityEventSpaceCharge2">Ushers</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[FacilityEventSpace][charge][]" value="3" id="FacilityEventSpaceCharge3" /><label for="FacilityEventSpaceCharge3">Additional Staffing</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[FacilityEventSpace][charge][]" value="4" id="FacilityEventSpaceCharge4" /><label for="FacilityEventSpaceCharge4">Special Lighting</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[FacilityEventSpace][charge][]" value="5" id="FacilityEventSpaceCharge5" /><label for="FacilityEventSpaceCharge5">Audio Visual Equipment</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="data[FacilityEventSpace][charge][]" value="6" id="FacilityEventSpaceCharge6" /><label for="FacilityEventSpaceCharge6">Audio Visual Technician</label></div>
```

---

my joinTable I created
CREATE TABLE `event_charges` (
`id` int (11) NOT NULL,
  `facility_event_spaces_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `facility_event_charges_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

---

my Models

```
<?php
class FacilityEventSpace extends AppModel {
var $name = 'FacilityEventSpace';
var $hasAndBelongstoMany = array('FacilityEventCharge' =>
                        array('className'    => 'FacilityEventCharge',
                              'joinTable' => 'event_charges',
                              'foreignKey'   => 'facility_event_spaces_id',
                              'associationForeignKey' => 'facility_event_charges_id',
                              'with' =>'EventCharge'
                        ),
                  );
} // end Model
?>
```

---

```
<?php
class FacilityEventCharge extends AppModel {

var $name = 'FacilityEventCharge';

} // end Model
?>
```

---

```
<?php
class EventCharge extends AppModel
{
 var $name = 'EventCharge';                     
} // end Model
?>
```

---

My controller - facility_event_spaces_controller.php

function add

```
$this->set('charges', $this->FacilityEventCharge->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'type'))  ));
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    if($this->FacilityEventSpace->save($this->data))
                {

                $this->flash('The event space has been saved.','/FacilityEventSpaces/');
                        return;
                } 
}
```

---

also, here's the facility_event_charges table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one way I found to save data to my separate table was:

```
$maxId = $this->FacilityEventSpace->getMaxId();
                    // routines for Charges
                    $charges = $this->data['FacilityEventSpace']['charge'];
                    $n = 0;
                    foreach ($charges as $key => $cost) {

                        $charge = array('EventCharge'=>array(
                        'id'=>'',
                        'facility_event_spaces_id'=>$maxId[0][0]['max(id)'],
                        'facility_event_charges_id'=>$cost
                        )
                        );
                        $this->EventCharge->save($charge['EventCharge']);
                        $n = $n + 1;
                    } // end charges
```

Comment: Since my checkboxes come from a separate table, 'facility_event_charges' and those that were "checked" get saved to a different table, 'event_charges' how can I render in my edit.ctp file, all the checkboxes including those that were selected checkboxes?